# Mocking list of objects in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, mocking, pytest

In my `FooClass` I've got `self.mylist` which consists of `MyObject`s and is being created from some database query.
So far in my tests I've been using `pytest` fixture:

```
    @fixture
    def mock_mylist():
        foo = FooClass()
        foo.mylist = MagicMock()
        return foo
```

It worked fine, when I had to tests methods, in which I needed `mylist` just "be some list". However, one of the method is relying on `mylist` and do some checks like

```
for el in mylist:
    if el.MyObject.a == 1 and el.MyObject.b == 2 and...
        #compare el.MyObject.c to some external value and process...
```

To sum up, I need a test `mylist` with mocked `MyObject`, but I would like to define somehow some of mocked `MyObject` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the objects in advance:

```
@fixture
def mock_mylist():
    foo = FooClass()
    foo.mylist = MagicMock()
    for el in foo.mylist:
        el.MyObject.a = 1
        el.MyObject.b = 2
        # …and…
    return foo
```