# How to mock a list of objects by side_effecting its attribute

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want to unittest the following function which takes a list of [RunInfo](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.entities.html#mlflow.entities.RunInfo) objects as argument.

```
def get_mses(runs):
    mse = []
    for r in runs:  
        metrics = mlflow.get_run(r.run_id).data.metrics
        mse.append(metrics['cv_mse'])
    
    return mse
```

While the main logic is around `metrics`, it does need to iterate the `runs` and grab the attribute `run_id` to retrieve information about each run. However I don't think I need to mock the actual `RunInfo` class, but rather some fake class with an attribute `run_id`. How do I mock this and create a list of objects by specifying the run_ids as simple as (1, 2, 3) using `side_effects`?

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481332/mocking-list-of-objects-in-python), but it is not exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something but why use `side_effects`? Wouldn't `runs = [unittest.mock.NonCallableMock(run_id=i) for i in range(1,4)]` do the job?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin This is awesome, works like a charm. I got "unittest has no attribute mock" error though so I had to do `from unittest import mock` and do the `NonCallableMock` thing

Comment: Glad to hear! Will make it an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to use `side_effects` for this purpose. `unittest.mock` has a [`NonCallableMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.NonCallableMock) class that can hold arbitrary attributes.

```
from unittest import mock

runs = [mock.NonCallableMock(run_id=i) for i in range(1,4)]
```